# Не работает Apache

Tags: apache

После установки Apache:pacman -S apache php php-apache mysqlпопробовал его запустить и получил ошибку: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for arch-pchttpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerNameпосле поиска по форумах добавил строчку ServerName localhost в /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf(в ArchWiki об этом ничего несказано) сервер всеравно не запускается (помойму сервер должен запускатся с дефолтними конфигами), как исправить?

PS: Файл /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost arch-pc::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost

Answer (score 1):

> NameVirtualHost *:80

В ports.conf пропишите, хотя можно и в apache.conf, не важно. Тем самым вы сделаете apache, name based сервером. А по факту ваша ошибка не должна приводить к краху apache, это всего лишь worning.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает

Comment: @Seriyyy95, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз.![alt text][1] (взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/RDEc8.png